# Restoring a file from windows 7 backup gives access is denied

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-backup

I have a sql database I accidentally deleted. I have a backup of the database with the windows backup that comes with windows 7. Every other file I can go in to previous versions and restore it, however when i get to the mdf and ldf file I get a error `You Need Permission from the computers administrator to make changes to this file.`

I am a administrator account. I have tried turning off UAC but it still says that. When I open the "previous versions" folder and click on the file to restore and go to security it says `You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings`

If I go in to advanced it says the same message on permissions, auditing and effective permissions. If I go in to owner it says "`Unable to display current owner.`" if I try to change the owner to me I get `Unable to set new owner on Cvti101330_Data. Access is denied`

The path of the file i want to restore is `\\localhost\E$\@GMT-2010.11.04-08.17.33\101330\Cvti101330_data.mdf` is there any kind of command line tool I can run to get my file back?

Comment: Can you log in as the owner of the file you are attempting to restore?

Comment: I suggest not using Windows 7 backup. Many people have problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

Mount the VHD backup file as readonly, then go into that location on the VHD using a tool like Total Commander, running as Administrator, to **copy** the file to your hard drive. Copying it will take the permissions of the target location.

Comment: How do I mount it?

Comment: Using Disk Management under Computer Management.

Comment: I could not find the vhd file to mount but running total commander and pointing it at \\localhost\E$\@GMT-2010.11.04-08.17.33\101330\ worked

Comment: Glad Total Commander was able to help.